# Is there a Continuous Deployment Framework?

Tags: validation, installation, continuous-deployment

We want to set up continuous deployment so that on every check in, the files are copied, sites are created and databases updated. This is working ok for now using lots of C# and calling it from C#.
We want to add Assertion/Checks to make sure the servers are the correct versions, urls are working, passwords are correct etc
The kind of thing I want is the SQL Server 2008 Installer, where it has a list of checks it performs before installing. I want to run this from unittests/powershell and if possible also add a GUI so that the systems team can "check" the state of the servers.
Is there a good tasks framework?

- Team City
- C#
- NUnit
- PowerShell
- IIS, SQL Server, MSMQ etc

Comment: For SharePoint but there is a project along those lines at http://sharepointinstaller.codeplex.com. It does some pre-install checks etc. Worth a look but I can't comment on the code quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TeamCity, and it is really, really easy to setup and get it running.
Check the Demos and Documentation.
http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Or u can refer to:
NUnitForms has a "hidden desktop" feature that will let you run unit tests from cc.net.

http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2007/09/winforms-testing-using-nunitforms.html http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/2007/09/hidden-desktops-and-nunitforms.html

If you want to use a single csproj and control elements like the assembly name based on a specific build configuration. Then you're looking for the Conditional element on MSBuild properties:

```
<AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release-Prod'">Foo</AssemblyName>
<AssemblyName Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release-Test'">Foo-Test</AssemblyName/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at OpsCode Chef or Puppet - what you're after is infrastructure automation. Both these tools support Windows automation now, and they both allow you to automate the building of environments.

You could also look at DbDeploy, a tool for controlling and tracking changes to databases.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Release Management built into TFS.
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx

It runs off of our gated check-ins so that all unit tests are run followed by all coded UI tests in our integration lab, then deploys to our servers (web, database, and service layers). It also handles making sure the servers have the proper configurations.
With this tool we are able to deploy to production after every check-in.